# How to group document snapshots from firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

[image]

My document snapshots have field 'name' and I want to create a map with name as key and arraylist of document snapshots as value.

```
private Map<String, ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshotMap = new HashMap<> ();

userRef.addSnapshotListener (new EventListener<QuerySnapshot> () {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
        if (value!=null && !value.isEmpty ()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.size (); i++) {
                DocumentSnapshot d = value.getDocuments ().get (i);
                String name = d.get ("name").toString ();
                ArrayList<DocumentSnapshot> arrayList = snapshotMap.get ("name");
                if (arrayList==null) arrayList = new ArrayList<> ();
                else Log.e ("tag13", "arraylist size= "+arrayList.size ());

                arrayList.add (d);
                Log.e ("tag13", "new arraylist size = "+arrayList.size ());

                snapshotMap.put (name, arrayList);
            }

            int x = snapshotMap.get ("Akhil").size ();
            int y = snapshotMap.get ("name2").size ();

            Log.e ("tag14", "x = "+ x);
            Log.e ("tag14", "y = "+ y);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is, all my arraylist returns only one element in array eventhough it has more elements with Akhil and name2

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. What do the `log` statements output?